# JSON.stringify renders div rather than as string

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a json response for my api. I have an object, lets say:

```
var video = new Object()
video.title = "Puppy";
video.html = "<div style='width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.338%; background-color: red;'></div>";
video.desc = "A dog";

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(video, null, 2);

$('pre').append(jsonString);
```

The problem is though that the div is actually rendered (so you see a big red box). Any idea why? What I want though is to keep the html as a string, so that the user can call the api, read the html text, and display that.

Comment: try something along the lines of `$('pre').text(jsonString)`

Comment: You might also try an <xmp> tag which does not render HTML

Comment: both answers are great - thanks guys. It turns out the problem was on my end. I should have been using res.json rather than creating an html page and showing the JSON content there